# c# How to click this submit button?

Tags: javascript, c#, web

I'm trying to make a program that makes Visual studio webclients login to kahoot.it, i now am able to enter the required information to login but have no way to click the submit button...

Here is the code of the button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-greyscale join ng-binding" blocking="" data-functional-selector="join-button-game-pin">Enter</button>
```

Kind regards,
Joep van Diessen

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        doc.GetElementById("inputSession").SetAttribute("Value", gpin);





    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement headElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement scriptElement = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
        IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptElement.DomElement;
        element.text = @"function sayHello() $('button[type=""submit""]').first().submit()";
        headElement.AppendChild(scriptElement);
        webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried submitting the form the button is part of ?

Comment: Is this Asp.Net webforms or MVC? It looks like you have a Windows app with a web browser control.

Comment: Winform. in Visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Assuming jquery

```
$('button[type="submit"]').first().submit()
```

Edit #1

```
element.text = @"function sayHello() { document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit(); }";
```

Comment: Hey,  im a c# noob... How  do i implement this in my code?

Comment: ahh, my program is in c#, so im not sure if i can. I dont know.

Comment: if you want to do web you need to learn JS. Plus this will be trivial if you spend a few hours learning. http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: can you post more detail on how you are populating some of the form at the moment

Comment: Hey, i have managed to execute this code using c#. When i do this using inspect element in FireFox it works fine. when i use the code method it gives me an error about an error in the java script. error: Line 1, char 21, error Expected '{'

Comment: without you posting the code i cant really help you. That error means that you're missing a { somewhere or have an extra }

Comment: I will add my code, please dont hate me its really newby

Comment: try my edit for line 5 of button2_Click. You really should use javascript in the web page though, not invoking it with c# :)

Comment: #edit.    Button clicking now works...  but it does not know that the gamepin has been entered